# django-storages not being installed on heroku deployment

Tags: django, heroku

I deployed my app on heroku and then when I check it says " Internal Server Error". When I looked up the logs, it contains the following blurb:

```
2012-07-23T11:31:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
2012-07-23T11:31:16+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named storages2012-07-23T11:31:16+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(name)
2012-07-23T11:31:18+00:00 heroku[router]: GET peaceful-plains-3853.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=2065
```

When I check the installation logs, it does not look like django-storages was installed. My requirements file does contain django-stoages. Its listed below:

```
Django==1.4
boto==2.5.2
django-storages==1.1.5
distribute==0.6.27
simplejson==2.6.0
gunicorn==0.14.2
```

So now, I'm completely stumped and not sure how to troubleshoot further.

Comment: one solution, admittedly round about, would be to download the source code for storages and then upload it as an app

Comment: That's a really bad idea =/ Not only will it not be installable, but a huge pain.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your build again. The pypi.python.org mirror may have been down when you initially deployed your application, which could have caused it not to be installed. Doing another git push (after you make a change to your app) should fix the issue.